# PHP Warning: print_r and debug_backtrace when passing a mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysqli, backtrace, debug-backtrace

I have a very complicated system which was opening and closing MySQLi connections every time it wanted to perform a query - of which it was doing about 40,000 of per given operation (inefficient, I know).  I decided to pass the mysqli connection between functions, to prevent this open-and-close-repeatedly inefficiency.

My problem is: when a query fails I wanted to email myself the `debug_backtrace()`, formatted in an easy-to-read format (so I wrap it in `print_r()`).  For some reason, I'm now getting a PHP warning that says `print_r(): Property access is not allowed yet in... on line XXX` where line XXX simply reads `addNotification("Backtrace: ".print_r(debug_backtrace(), true), "debug");`

**Is there some reason that `print_r()` doesn't like `debug_backtrace()` when one of the passed parameters in the backtrace is an `mysqli_connect` object?**  Does the mysqli_connect lack a toString function?

**EDIT** After a little more research I've found that you CAN call `print_r` or `var_dump` on a `mysqli_connect` object, but if that object is `mysqli_close`d it causes this warning.  If it is closed and `unset` it is okay.

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` only returns an object and has no other methods associated with it.

Answer (score -1):

See the example here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

it's using var_dump instead of print_r

my personal favorite is var_export, because it creates php readable format.